# How to install Realtek 8822CE WiFi driver?

Tags: wifi

**realtek 8822CE**

Hi everyone. I want to install elementary OS to my laptop. After installation, I do not have a network, I can get it only by connecting a USB modem.
And so, I tried to install drivers from https://github.com/bserem/Realtek-RTL8822x-Linux, but with no success.
Previously, I saw the inscription "no cable inserted", but now I just see "no network". I searched for the driver via additional drivers, but it didn't find anything. Help me please! I really want to work on elementary OS in my laptop!

Answer (score 0):

I've used this advice for 8822ce driver: https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/realtek.html